How do I write my own SwiftUI ScrollView that will respect a lazy subview?
I am trying to write my own MyScrollView to manage scroll. I am doing this because I want to have a LazyVStack with items that have varying heights and for which I can scroll to any item inside. So, this is what I began with:
ScrollView {
    LazyVStack {
        ForEach(itemsWithVaryingHeights, id: \.key) { 
            ViewWithVariableHeight($0)
        }
    }.scrollTargetLayout()
}

Evidently, it is impossible to programmatically reliably scroll to a particular item since SwiftUI does not know how big my views are and gets confused which offset to scroll to.
Fine. I can calculate the height of my own SectionViews and manage my own scroll. So I thought to create my own barebones version of ScrollView:
struct MyScrollView<Child> : View where Child : View {
    @State var offsetY: CGFloat = 0
    public var child: Child
    
    init(@ViewBuilder child: () -> Child) {
        self.child = child()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        child
            .offset(y: offsetY)
            .gesture(
                DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { value in
                        offsetY = value.translation.height
                    }
                    .onEnded { value in
                        let nextScrollPosition = value.predictedEndTranslation.height
                        withAnimation(.spring()) {
                        offsetY = nextScrollPosition
                    }
            }
        )
    }
}

Then use it like so:
MyScrollView {
    LazyVStack {
        ForEach(itemsWithVaryingHeights, id: \.key) { 
            ViewWithVariableHeight($0)
        }
    }
}

This does not work as I expect since the entire LazyVStack is rendered, essentially not being lazy anymore. I am hoping I could get an understanding why that is. I thought that SwiftUI's ScrollView didn't know anything about how lazy or not the child view is. But in this case, it looks like it does handle lazy views differently somehow?
How can I replicate what ScrollView does? I am also all ears if someone can suggest a better approach to solve my problem.

"it looks like it does handle lazy views differently somehow?" Yes, ScrollView is special. Under the hood it is implemented using a UIScrollView subclass called HostingScrollView internal to SwiftUI. You can try to access this UIScrollView using SwiftUI-Introspect and set the contentOffset directly. Otherwise you need to reinvent your own lazy stack too.

By the way, .scrollTargetLayout() should be applied to the LazyVStack, not the ForEach.

@Sweeper yes, it was a typo with scrollTargetLayout. Didn't know about SwiftUI-Introspect, thanks for that. I'll look into it. If my idea is completely insane, I am very open to trying other things if you can think of them.
